# SQL Server out of memory

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I got this error running a query that goes against 2 tables with combined 50k rows.

```
An error occurred while executing batch. 
Error message is: Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.
```

How do I get around this?

**Edit**

I get this when I run DBCC MEMORYSTATUS

```
Msg 2571, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
User 'XXXX\YYYY' does not have permission to run DBCC memorystatus.
```

**New Edit**

The server worked fine the next morning without reboots or anything else.

Comment: How much disk space do you have left? Probably transaction log file grew to the disk space limit.

Comment: Also check it tempdb is on the drive which is full and can grow, although error message doesn't specifically indicate that

Comment: Umm, 25k rows X 25k rows = 625MM joined rows.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: They are in an EXISTS with a JOIN. My total is 50K, not 625MM

Comment: @Lukasz Lysic: C drive has 13GB free and D drive has 225GB free

Comment: @galets: both my HDDs have a ton of space (13GB and 225GB respectively) as seen in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Can you show your actual query?

Comment: And what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @Raj: If you don't have permission to run `DBCC MEMORYSTATUS`, maybe you are not the right person for solving this problem.  Do you have a dbo or sysadmin who maintains SQL server?

Comment: My DBA is :) AWOL. The server worked fine the next morning.

Comment: @Jerry Bullard: SQL 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it error 701, 801 or 802?

You need to investigate what is consuming the memory, see:

- [How to use the DBCC MEMORYSTATUS command to monitor memory usage on SQL Server 2005](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907877)
- [INF: Using DBCC MEMORYSTATUS to Monitor SQL Server Memory Usage](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/271624) for SQL 2000.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check what is the growth setting for temp db and for that particular Database?

Please ensure that the logfiles of temp db and that database are not set to restricted growth?

Can you check the available memory of the system while you are running the batch?

Answer (score 0):

What is the query? Did you accidentally do a cross join?

Comment: The query was EXISTS with a JOIN